# How to detect text change of an entry in tkinter Python

Tags: python, events

How can detect that a user entering characters in tkinter entry ?
I want to calculate the total cost from 2 different entry. here is my code but does not work!

```py
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def calculate_total_cost(event):
    if count_ent.get().isdigit() and unit_cost_ent.get().isdigit():
            total_cost=int(count_ent.get())*int(unit_cost_ent.get())
            print(total_cost)

count_ent=Entry(root).pack()
unit_cost_ent=Entry(root).pack()
unit_cost_ent.bind("<key>",calculate_total_cost)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you can add `Button` to execute function. You can bind event `<Return>` to run code when you press `ENTER`/`RETURN`, You assign `StringVar` to `Entry` as `textvariable` and use `trace` to assign function to StringVar and it will execute this function when it changes text in `StringVar` . You can bind even `<FocusOut>` to run function when you jump to another widget. And similar you can use `validatecommand=`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, insert value in both entry and press enter, you will get the results. Although your questions is also not cleared, but from your statement I decided that you are facing issue of "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'"...
By executing the below code, I hope you will get your answer. First execute this simple program, you will get the desired output in terminal.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def calculate_total_cost(event):
    if count_ent.get().isdigit() and unit_cost_ent.get().isdigit():
         total_cost=int(count_ent.get())*int(unit_cost_ent.get())
         print(total_cost)


count_ent=Entry(root)
count_ent.pack()
# count_ent.insert(0, value1)
unit_cost_ent=Entry(root)
unit_cost_ent.pack()
# unit_cost_ent.insert(0, value2)

unit_cost_ent.bind("<Return>",calculate_total_cost)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your code is working , but I want to use an event that call the "calculate_total_cost" by entering every character in the entry. whats that event name?

Comment: @JalalAlipoor it is `<Key>` (or `<KeyPress>`) with upper `K`. But it runs function before adding char - so it gets value without last char. Better can be `<KeyRelease>` which will execute function after adding char to `Entry`,

Comment: Thanks a lot , the true event was keyrelease. Thank you